# Connection state is opened but not valid?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection

I have this code that I use for copy one table to another, but I got error while executing command statement.

Error says that connection is not open or valid. When I debug I can see it is opened.
Really don't know why is not valid.

```
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con2"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_base"), con);
int nRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
con.Close();
if (nRows > 0)
{
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO temp_data SELECT * FROM data");
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Everything goes well until last command:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO temp_data SELECT * FROM data");
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Is this even possible if these two database are on different servers? Maybe I need to have two connections opened at the same time or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the connection object to the `MySqlCommand` constructor:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO temp_data SELECT * FROM data", con);
```

Comment: OMG I didn't see that :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con2"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_base");
        int nRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (nRows > 0)
        {
            using (var conn2 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn2.Open();
                using (var cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd2.CommandText ="INSERT INTO temp_data SELECT * FROM data";
                    cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```